# How to remove duplicate entries and condsolidate data Excel 2013

Tags: excel, excel-2013

What is the easiest way to convert this data set,

[image]

into this data set?

[image]

Basically, I want to get rid of the duplicate Equipment numbers and consolidate the data for each into a single row.

Comment: Maybe its just on my computer ... but I can't see either of the data sets

Comment: They link to images saved on dropbox, since I have to have 10 reputation points to post images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the data range, click Insert - Pivot table.

Drag Equipment Number to the Rows area, the rest fields to the Data area.
Change aggregation function on all data area fields from Count to Sum.
In the table settings, untick grand totals for rows and columns.